# Convert Dataframe column to time format in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I have a dataframe column which looks like this :

[image]

It reads `M:S.MS`. How can I convert it into a `M:S:MS timeformat` so I can plot it as a time series graph?

If I plot it as it is, python throws an `Invalid literal for float()` error.

> Note
>    : This dataframe contains one hour worth of data. `Values between
>   0:0.0 - 59:59.9`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['00:02.0','00:05:0','00:08.1']})

print (df)
      date
0  00:02.0
1  00:05:0
2  00:08.1
```

It is possible convert to `datetime`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%M:%S.%f')
print (df)
                     date
0 1900-01-01 00:00:02.000
1 1900-01-01 00:00:05.000
2 1900-01-01 00:00:08.100
```

Or to `timedelta`s:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['date'].radd('00:'))
print (df)
             date
0        00:00:02
1        00:00:05
2 00:00:08.100000
```

EDIT:

For custom date use:

```
date = '2015-01-04'

td = pd.to_datetime(date) - pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%M:%S.%f') + td
print (df)
                     date
0 2015-01-04 00:00:02.000
1 2015-01-04 00:00:05.000
2 2015-01-04 00:00:08.100
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But is there a way to change the '1900-01-01' to another date for all the rows?

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is what I was looking for. 
But, can you also edit to add a custom hour? thank you

Comment: Thanks jezrael, I really appreciate it. This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Im seeing `radd` for the first time